# Outlook 2010 with Google Calendar

Tags: outlook, calendar

So, I use outlook for work (outlook 2010). I have had to add my emails manually to my personal phone via active sync. I am unable to find a way to see my calendar. The ideal way i am hoping is to add my outlook calendar to my google calendar. any suggestions?

Comment: You could export your Outlook calendar to Google Calendar.

For more information, Please refer to this link:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-an-outlook-calendar-to-google-calendar-662fa3bb-0794-4b18-add8-9968b665f4e6

Comment: That link is for Outlook for Office 365 Outlook 2019 Outlook 2016 Outlook 2013 not 2010. thank you though.